# www-data permissions?

Tags: apache, permissions, sudo

So I have a directory in /var/www (called cake) and I need to allow www-data to write to it, but I also want to write to it (without having to use sudo). I'm afraid to change the permissions to 777 in case some other user on my machine (or a hacker) attempts to modify files in that directory. How do I only allow access for myself and Apache's www-data?

Answer (score 214, accepted):

```
sudo chown -R yourname:www-data cake
```

then

```
sudo chmod -R g+s cake
```

First command changes owner and group.

Second command adds s attribute which will keep new files and directories within cake having the same group permissions.

Comment: Why is the chmod g+s recursive?

Comment: didn't know about g+s. very very handy!

Comment: what can the user do with files created by www-data in cake itself, and files created by www-data in a directory which is created by www-data? for example, about edit, rename, delete operations? as i understand, renaming and deleting are not possible inside directory created by www-data, and editing of files creaed by www-data is not possible for user at all.

Answer (score 54):

As stated in [an article by Slicehost](http://articles.slicehost.com/2007/9/18/apache-virtual-hosts-permissions):

> ### User setup
>
> So let's start by adding the main user to the Apache user group:
>
> ```
> sudo usermod -a -G www-data demo
> ```
>
> That adds the user 'demo' to the 'www-data' group. Do ensure you use
>   both the -a and the -G options with the usermod command shown above.
>
> You will need to log out and log back in again to enable the group
>   change.
>
> Check the groups now:
>
> ```
> groups
> ...
> # demo www-data
> ```
>
> So now I am a member of two groups: My own (demo) and the Apache group
>   (www-data).
>
> ### Folder setup
>
> Now we need to ensure the public_html folder is owned by the main user
>   (demo) and is part of the Apache group (www-data).
>
> Let's set that up:
>
> ```
> sudo chgrp -R www-data /home/demo/public_html
> ```
>
> As we are talking about permissions I'll add a quick note regarding
>   the sudo command: It's a good habit to use absolute paths
>   (/home/demo/public_html) as shown above rather than relative paths
>   (~/public_html). It ensures sudo is being used in the correct
>   location.
>
> If you have a public_html folder with symlinks in place then be
>   careful with that command as it will follow the symlinks. In those
>   cases of a working public_html folder, change each folder by hand.
>
> ### Setgid
>
> Good so far, but remember the command we just gave only affects
>   existing folders. What about anything new?
>
> We can set the ownership so anything new is also in the 'www-data'
>   group.
>
> The first command will change the permissions for the public_html
>   directory to include the "setgid" bit:
>
> ```
> sudo chmod 2750 /home/demo/public_html
> ```
>
> That will ensure that any new files are given the group 'www-data'. If
>   you have subdirectories, you'll want to run that command for each
>   subdirectory (this type of permission doesn't work with '-R').
>   Fortunately new subdirectories will be created with the 'setgid' bit
>   set automatically.
>
> If we need to allow write access to Apache, to an uploads directory
>   for example, then set the permissions for that directory like so:
>
> ```
> sudo chmod 2770 /home/demo/public_html/domain1.com/public/uploads
> ```
>
> The permissions only need to be set once as new files will
>   automatically be assigned the correct ownership.

Comment: This solution works for me. Before that, I always run the server from terminal using root user. With this solution, I can upload file to directory that has permission 770. This is awesome, because before that I can only upload file using 777 permission.

Answer (score 5):

Let's say you want to sftp into a directory sharing reading, writing and executing permissions with www-data, this is what you should do:

1 - Add yourself to www-data group

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data <your_user>
```

2 - Sets the wanted user:group ownership for your folder and files recursively

```
sudo chown -R <your_user>:www-data <your_folder>
```

3 - This adds permissions (read write execute) to all users (a+rwx); Restrict permissions from others (o-rwx); Sets the same (folder inherited) user:group for every new file created under that directory (ug+s). This will be executed recursively and only in folder (probably exactly what you want)

```
sudo find <folder_name> -type d -exec chmod a+rwx,o-rwx,ug+s {} +
```