# Cherokee: accessing uwsgi configuration file

Tags: file-permissions, uwsgi, ubuntu-13.10, http-status-code-503, cherokee

I'm running into a permissions problem with Cherokee+uWSGI on Ubuntu Server 13.10 intended for a Django production environment. When I start uWSGI manually as root user prior to launching cherokee, everything goes smooth:

```
sudo uwsgi --ini /home/instytut21/instytut21l/instytut21/uwsgi.ini
```

But when I try to access the site through the server (running as www-data) without that, I keep getting a `503 Service Unavailable` response and the following message in the logs:

```
sudo cat /var/log/cherokee/instytut21.error.log
realpath() of /home/instytut21/instytut21.pl/instytut21/uwsgi.ini failed:
[core/utils.c line 3574]
```

I've spent a good while trying to figure out what causes the problem. I've tried giving ownership to `$USER:www-data` and `www-data:www-data` with all kinds of file permissions ranging from `600` to `777`.

I don't want to run the server as root for security reasons. How can I make the ini file accessible to cherokee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to a similar problem at [www-data permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133024/www-data-permissions) . I slightly modified it and solved my problem by executing the following commands.

Own the whole directory by me and group www-data:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data /home/instytut21/instytut21.pl/
```

Grant all permissions to the group:

```
sudo chmod -R g+rwx /home/instytut21/instytut21.pl/
```

Ensure all uploaded filed get the same permissions:

```
sudo chmod -R g+s /home/instytut21/instytut21.pl/
```