# XAMPP: How to make apache webserver owner of folder /htdocs

Tags: apache, usergroups

I am using XAMPP and apache as webserver. I have permission problems with a website of mine that requires write access to a temporary folder in the project folder /htdocs/myProject/tmp

It think my problem is that my site runs on my localhost and I copied the project with my regular desktop user into the htdocs folder. Apache seems to lack write permissions.

My question is now: How do I found out which user group apache belongs to in order to make that group owner of the folder? That should fix my permission problem, shouldn't?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the Apache (Webserver) has an own user called "www-data". Maybe an already answered question on SO has a solution, which you can use.

- The used command relies on a linux-based system and that you navigated in a terminal to a directory, where /htdocs is located.
- This command in the answer of the link below allows you as a humanoid user to write and work in this specified directory.
- You add www-data (Apache) to use this directory, too.
- New files of that **[chown](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchown.htm)**'ed directory will 'inherit' the owners.

The Link and further descriptions can be found here on Stackoverflow.com:
[www-data permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9133067/674442)