# Laravel XAMPP Mac The stream or file "/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to run an existing Laravel project on my localhost but when I try to run the dam thing I get this error:

> The stream or file "/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened:
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied

I have tried the following:

`chmod -R 775 storage` and `chmod -R 777 storage`

Still nothing, I have even tried to do `chgrp -R www-data my-project` and I get this error in terminal

```
chgrp: www-data: illegal group name
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if it was linux, I would tell you to check the owner of the file, it should be the virtual host owner if it was set. Maybe windows needs that too. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24141556/xampp-how-to-make-apache-webserver-owner-of-folder-htdocs

Comment: @AmitozDeol When I do that, I get this error: file_put_contents(/storage/framework/cache/data/9c/17/9c17a99b76c7d84c467be3b9936a19ac171000a1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Delete those cache files. It'll get generated again

Comment: @AmitozDeol How do I do that?

Comment: `rm -R storage/framework/cache/data`

Comment: @AmitozDeol I still get the same error

Comment: @user979331 do you have a storage/framework/cache/data directory?

Comment: @loic.lopez after checking the data folder does not exists.....but I copied this from a server, how was it able run on a server.

Comment: which `user group` is running your laravel app?

Comment: @user979331 you can juste create the data folder by : `mkdir -p storage/framework/cache/data`

Answer (score 21):

Navigate to the project directory and run

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage/*
```

Answer (score 7):

#### This is my solution.

First you need to run `php artisan cache:clear` from the project directory, then `chmod -R 777 app/storage` and finally `composer dump-autoload` and now it will be working fine..

illegal group name actually means that the group you're specifying(after www-data going username).You need to either create the group, stop specifying a group, or specify a group that exists.

Comment: try composer dump-autoload

Comment: I tried that and it says Generated optimized autoload files containing 4054 classes, but the error still remains.

Comment: about ilegal group name when you try www-data you need using username not name of project. Or using specify a group that exist

Comment: In addition to Ismoils solution:You have to change the permission on your project folder:Right click>getInfo>Sharing&Permissions and change them to read&write and make sure you include all the files and folders inside as well:

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! After about 20 minutes breaking my head.