# Run Debian Bash script with PHP

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, debian

I'm having trouble to run a bash file using PHP.

PHP File :

```
chdir('/var/www/PATH/inc/bash/');
exec('./status.sh argument, $output);
```

Bash File :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'test' >> /var/www/PATH/inc/bashOutput/test.txt
```

PHP File (ls -al handler.func.php) :

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 461 Jul  5 11:35 handler.func.php
```

Bash File (ls -al status.sh) :

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 255 Jul  5 11:39 status.sh
```

Script is working using through root with SSH.

I'm not a pro on Linux.
But I think it's a problem come with the file owner.

But I have already done some damages in the past with "chown" so If it is indead the problem I would prefer some guidance from more experienced people.

Thanks for you help,
Konorr.

Comment: What's the exact error that you get when you access that script in a browser?

Comment: you forgot the second quotation mark in the exec command

Comment: Please don't append _solved_ to your title. Instead accept an answer. This will tell others that the question has now been solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`Script is working using through root with SSH.` There is the problem. When a PHP script run via a web request it usually runs as the user www-data. In anycase `<?php exec('./status.sh argument, $output);?>` in a security hole. Most server admins would have this disabled.

Your other option is to put `sudo` in your exec function `exec('sudo bash /var/www/PATH/inc/bash/status.sh')`. Along with running the script with an absolute path `bash /var/www/PATH/inc/bash/status.sh`

Why can't you run a cron on your script?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you answer but unfortunatly it didn't worked for me.

I search a litle more about file owners.

I did few changes

I made in these change :

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/PATH
usermod -a -G www-data user
chgrp -R www-data /var/www/PATH
chmod 2750 /var/www/PATH
chmod 2750 /var/www/PATH/inc/bash
```

It wasn't yet working till I removed the sudo from the EXEC function.
So I don't know from which point my problem was already fixed.

I followed this article : [www-data permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133024/www-data-permissions)

Thanks for you time and in the hope it can help someone else.

Comment: please make sure you `accept` your own answer (after the grace period has expired and you have collected enough points to do so), so it is properly marked as *resolved*.