# using sftp (filezilla) to connect to google cloud instance

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, filezilla, google-cloud-sdk

I've so far been able to use google cloud sdk to try and connect to a VM instance on google cloud it also created a .ssh folder on my windows user account and at the same time a new user on the online VM with a similar name "DIGIVILLE"

here's the output from filezilla

```
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Connecting to 35.185.21.196...
Response:   fzSftp started
Command:    keyfile "C:\Documents and Settings\DIGIVILLE\.ssh\google_compute_engine.ppk"
Command:    open "root@35.185.21.196" 22
Error:  Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Connecting to 35.185.21.196...
Response:   fzSftp started
Command:    keyfile "C:\Documents and Settings\DIGIVILLE\.ssh\google_compute_engine.ppk"
Command:    open "digiville@35.185.21.196" 22
Error:  Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Connecting to 35.185.21.196...
Response:   fzSftp started
Command:    keyfile "C:\Documents and Settings\DIGIVILLE\.ssh\google_compute_engine.ppk"
Command:    open "digiville@35.185.21.196" 22
Error:  Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

and the settings

[image]

including the ppk file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the first screenshot, in My Sites -> New site -> Logon Type, you have to select "Key file".

If you need to generate a key file and apply it to the project, you can follow the instructions here:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#createsshkeys
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#edit-ssh-metadata

Comment: the second page shows the .ppk file used in edit > settings >sftp

Comment: Setting the "Logon Type" field to "Interactive" will use password autentification. I am not sure it's possible do add a site from the Site Manager and use the key from Edit-> Preferences-> SSL, the second screenshot.

The keys in Edit-> Preferences-> SSL will be used if you connect using the [Quickconnect bar](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Using#Using_the_Quick_Connect_bar).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In case you choose "interactive" Logon Type check if your VM permit passwordAuthentication. On your server, type `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config` and change passwordAuthentication field to "yes" if it is "no".

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem like so.

First add your username(sftp username in mycase) in group www-data then assign group www-data as an owner and finally grant permission to www folder.

```
sudo adduser <username> www-data
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R g+rwX /var/www
```

remember to restart filezilla or any sftp client you are using so the changes can take effect.

[Permission in google cloud sftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45188975/permission-in-google-cloud-sftp)